# Android: Not able to experiment on own?

Tags: learning, errors, android-development

I have just started learning Android App Development a few days ago, with prior knowledge of C/C++, HTML and CSS.

This is the situation I am facing Repeatedly:

I am learning from a Video Tutorial Series, after each video, or each few videos, I say myself: Let's use what I have just learnt in the simple (and also "meaningless") app that I have made so far by watching the tutorials.

I start implementing it, but then after a few minutes, I realize that I cannot do it because I do not know a few other syntax related to the particular thing, (or) I do not know whether these things can be combined with these other things by the use of . (dot).

Whatever I try, I get either an error in eclipse or "Sorry...the app com.example.simple has stopped unexpectedly...." when the app runs.

Then I search StackOverflow, Google and learn that what I want to implement requires learning about a few more classes, syntax and creating a few more java classes.

I am not able to experiment on my own. Is it normal? Is it the HARD-WAY in which one is supposed to learn?

Should I first learn Java and then come back to Android - would that be helpful?

Comment: Yes, you definitely should learn the language you are using from simple examples, before trying to learn a complex platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am really happy to see that you want to do Android programming, it is advised to learn Java before learning Android. It is something you don't know HTML but want to create a web page.

But on the start you can implement very simple hello world type of example and grasp the concepts before jumping into programming.

"Language does not matter, logic does". keep trying and don't give up on this.

Eclipse is quite powerful to debug and analyze errors. You could post some code errors might someone can give you right guidance.

Comment: It's not mandatory to learn Java if you use one of the cross-platform toolkits like PhoneGap, Appcelerator and so on.

Comment: "it is *mandatory* to learn Java... " - not for any definition of 'mandatory' that I'm aware of.  I think the word you are looking for is "recommended"

Comment: Well, that is kinda the same as saying that it's recommended to learn how to swim before jumping off a cruise ship. If you want to do Android programming and not just create HTML based apps, you SHOULD know Java.

Comment: I have to agree with @cseder on this.  Trying to get into Android without learning Java (by way of PhoneGap or similar) is - to extend his metaphor - like using a life jacket without knowing how to swim.  You'll probably get something done, but not nearly as much as you could.

Comment: Appcelerator creates native Android apps, FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend spending some time studying Java before jumping into the fray of Android development, as it adds a whole layor or two of complexity on top of the language. I am fairly new to both Android and Java, but [Java in a Nutshell](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007737.do) really helped get to grips with the Java part of Android development. This book is really great in explaining the basics(the first few chapters) and differences to C++.